# Identifying selected values in a <select> input field in php

Tags: php

I am working with an update page wherein I use a `<select>` input field and I want to get the `days` from my database and make it a  `selected` value of the  input field. It worked , but my problem is when those selected days is being set as `selected` in the  control the other days is being duplicated. 

For example:

```
<select name="day[]">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option>Monday</option>
    <option>Tuesday</option>
    <option>Wednesday</option>
    <option>Thursday</option>
    <option>Friday</option>
    <option>Saturday</option>
    <option>Sunday</option>
</select>       

my_days = array('Monday','Wednesday','Friday');
```

So in this example `Monday`, `Wednesday`,`Friday` will be selected without duplication
 Here is my code:

```
   <?php
        $day = $rows_load['day'];
        $days = explode(',', $day);
        $n = count($days);
         $the_days = array(
             'Monday' => 'Monday',
             'Tuesday' => 'Tuesday',
             'Wednesday' => 'Wednesday',
             'Thursday' => 'Thursday',
             'Friday' => 'Friday',
             'Saturday' => 'Saturday',
             'Sunday' => 'Sunday',
            );
     ?>

    <select data-placeholder="SELECT A DAY" multiple class="chosen-select chzn-select" tabindex="8" name="day[]" id="day" style="width:95%; " align="left" required>
        <option value=""></option>
        <?php 
        for($x = 0;$x < $n; $x ++){ 
         echo "<option selected>".$the_days[ $days[ $x ] ] ."</option>";
        }
        ?>

        <option>Monday</option>
        <option>Tuesday</option>
        <option>Wednesday</option>
        <option>Thursday</option>
        <option>Friday</option>
        <option>Saturday</option>
        <option>Sunday</option>
    </select>
```

See links for image reference

http://postimg.org/image/pqk2sn4kn/ - Here is the output of the code above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
foreach ($the_days as $day_name) {
    if (in_array($day_name, $days)) {
        echo '<option selected>';
    } else {
        echo '<option>';
    }
    echo $day_name . '</option>';
}
```

[DEMO](http://ideone.com/SdiTD5)

Comment: Working for me. See the demo.